# How to look up items with id for one controller from another controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two controllers where the first one contains a list of items:

```
$scope.items = [{id:1, desc:'desc1'},{id:2, desc:'desc2'}...];
```

The second one binds to a template which displays a list of items selected:

```
$scope.myitems = [1,2,3,...]; // ids only

 <div ng-repeat="item in myitems">
   {{item.id}} / {{item.desc}}
 </div>
```

How can I look up the item desc in the ng-repeat of the second controller from the item list of the first controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing data between controllers is best achieved via services/factories, an alternative is to use scope inheritance.

## 1. Factory/Service

```
angular.module('yourModule').factory('itemService', itemService);

    function itemService() {
         var items =  [{id:1, desc:'desc1'},{id:2, desc:'desc2'}...];
         return {
             findItemById: findItemById
         }
         
        function findItemById(id) {
            //logic to find item by id
        }
    }
```

Inject this factory in your controllers and add more functions if needed.

## 2. Scope inheritance

The key here is to nest your childcontroller, which I presume is the one with the ids.

```
<div ng-controller="topCtrl">
   <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="item in myitems">
         {{item.id}} / {{item.desc}}
      </div>
   
   </div>
</div>
```

With this option, any controller that is nested within the topCtrl in the view has access to the topCtrl scoped variables.

A third option would be to store the data in the $rootScope, which is actually also a sort of scope inheritance (all scopes except for isolated directive scopes inherit from the rootScope), but that's probably not a good idea for your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use inheritance concept:

```
var app = angular.module(....);

app.controller('FirstCtrl ', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{id:1, desc:'desc1'},{id:2, desc:'desc2'}...];
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {
  $controller('FirstCtrl', {$scope: $scope}); // $scope.items now available

});
```

Advantage over the $rootScope solution:

- second controller will always have access to `items`, even if first controller is not instantiated
- `items` array may be changed only by these two controllers, and not anyone other

Main flaw of this approach is that `SecondCtrl` will have access to any scope variable of the `FirstCtrl` and not only `items` array

**EDIT.** IMHO Factory/Service approach mentioned by @NexusDuck is the best one (composition over inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign values to $rootScope.items in first controller, then try to access in second controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $emit and $on.

EX: 
In First controller add

```
$scope.$emit('eventName', $scope.items);
};
```

And also pass $scope.items.

In Second Controller Add

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function (event, args) {
    $scope.items = args;
});
```

args hold $scope.items value and is assign to $scope.items in second controlle, so now ng-repeat display value of $scope.items of First Controller.